# sparklyr help: spark_read_csv returns an error

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I have a 3GB csv file called accelerometer.csv on my cpu. I wanted to read it into Spark using R and the sparklyr package just as an experiment before importing seriously big data (180 GB).

I used this code here:

```
spark_c <- spark_connect(master = "local")
spark_version(sc = spark_c)
acc <- spark_read_csv(sc = spark_conn, name = "accelerometer.csv")
```

This returns error:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 13.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 13, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:430)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:422)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at sparklyr.Utils$.collectColumnString(utils.scala:59)
    at sparklyr.Utils$.collectColumn(utils.scala:73)
    at sparklyr.Utils.collectColumn(utils.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:94)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:89)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:55)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:49)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:430)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:422)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: What version of sparklyr are you using? Also, pretty minor but `spark_conn` is going into your read method instead of `spark_c`. We typically use `sc` for the context object.

Comment: @Dan I'm using 0.5.6